Flutter Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Cannot find type 'PhoneNumberKit' in scope error
I am getting Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Cannot find type 'PhoneNumberKit' in scope error and I have tried
Adding pod 'PhoneNumberKit', '~> 4.0.1' to PodFile.
But no luck.
I also tried deleting podlock file and reinstalling, flutter clean and stuff but nothing seems to work.
how can I find what package is using this so I can just delete it?

Is PhoneNumberKit the name of a class? Did you include the right header file?

Oh, I had to check what packages were using that. It was Int'l number package. So I removed that and the error was gone!
